# Increasing max # of items in Firefox for Android history

Tags: firefox-for-android, history

A couple days ago I decided to give Firefox for Android another chance, and it turns out its history only goes back 100 items! How do I fix this? I want unlimited history, as I've set up on my Pale Moon on PC, or at least a way to backup and import, as the FEBE extension does on PC (I don't have root on my phone).

I tried the `places.history.expiration.max_pages` method, but it does nothing (probably because, as I gather, FF for Android doesn't use places.sqlite). Other FF Android clones I tried have the same problem.

(Frankly I'm a little disturbed by the amount of extensions aimed at *deleting* history. In this day and age of ubiquitous internet traffic logging, why do people want to be the only ones not to have access to their browsing history?)